# Advantages of LS-SVM over SVM

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm

My teacher asked me to do a research on LS-SVM, I know what is LS-SVM and how its mathematically different from SVM. I have found lots of papers that shows that for large-scale problems LS-SVM have some advantages over SVM. But I was wondering if there are other reasons to use LS-SVM. I have read somewhere that:

> One of the original dreams in the neural networks area is to make a
>   universal class of models (such as MLPs) generally applicable to a
>   wide range of applications.

And I assume that with LS-SVM you can achieve this goal. Am I right?
What Problems are LS-SVM capable of solving that regular SVM can’t handle?

Comment: What is LS-SVM?

Comment: @C11H17N2O2SNa Least squares support vector machine

Answer (score 1):

Short answer for now, but LS-SVM, being derived from Ridge Regression (it has the same functional form), results in a linear problem, while the SVM requires the solution of a quadratic problem. That's about it.